# Recursive construction using the This pointer

Tags: c++, recursion, constructor, this

This code compiles and runs. (Run at your own risk). When it runs, it endlessly prints "Constr beg" as could be predicted. My question is, does the recursion create one object or multiple objects? If multiple objects are being created, how does that happen when the 'this' pointer is being used as the constructor parameter?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
private:
    A* m_p;
public:
    A() = delete;
    A(A* m_p) {
        cout << "Constr beg" << endl;
        m_p = new A{this};
        cout << "Constr end" << endl;
    }
    ~A() {
        cout << "Destr beg" << endl;
        if (m_p != nullptr) {
            delete this;
        }
        cout << "Destr end" << endl;
    }   
};

int main()
{
    // A a(A&);
    A* pA{nullptr};
    A b(pA);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stupid code - no value to anybody to have an answer to this question

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, does the recursion create one object or multiple objects?

The recursion creates instances of your class without any condition to stop it. You'll end up with a stack overflow, most likely.

Answer (score 0):

> If multiple objects are being created, how does that happen when the 'this' pointer is being used as the constructor parameter?

You're never using the parameter in the constructor, so how could its value possibly affect anything?

The first line (`A* pA{nullptr};`) creates a pointer and assigns it the value `nullptr`, so isn't actually invoking the constructor at all. Consider e.g. `unsigned foo{0};` or `A* pA = nullptr;`.

The second line creates a new object of type A named 'b', and passes nullptr as the argument to the constructor (but that's never used). Inside the constructor, another object of type A is used, and passed the address of the A object that was just created (i.e. the address of main()'s '`b`'), which is again not used for anything. Since that in turn recursively creates new objects it probably never returns; but if it did, the address of that new object would be assigned to the argument `m_p` which would then be discarded when (if) the constructor returned.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it so maybe we can ease on the negative votes?